# VBScript select substring after last occurrence of "|"

Tags: vbscript

I've this string:

```
TEST|TEST1|TEST3|TEST4|TEST5|TEST6|TEST7|TEST8|
```

I need to select `TEST8` using VBS. Is there a better way then using `MID/INSTR`? For example, selecting directly only the characters UNTIL `|` from right to left?

PS.: I only have these functions available:

Ascii
Char
Compare 
DigText 
Format
InStr
LCase
Len 
Left
LTrim
Mid 
Right
RTrim
Trim
UCase

Comment: You have InStr, but Not InStrRev?  Is this some kind of Common Core stuff?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have InStrRev available

Comment: A hideously ugly scenario would be to loop through reading one char from the right at a time until you hit the delimiter, and then getting the Right of that value.  It uses all the functions you can use, assuming you're allowed to use a loop construct too.  Your function limitations are baffling.  Can you explain why they exist?

Comment: @Andrew I am using a custom application that has some VBS functions implemented. I was not aware that not all functions are available so my apologies. I cannot have a loop I can only have IF statements.

Comment: If you can't use `Split`, a combination of `InStr` and `Mid` is your best option, AFAICS.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)(), if your data is a string with parts separated by a simple separator; use [UBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhx59d0t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)() to get at the last element in a flexible way:

```
>> s = "TEST|TEST1|TEST3|TEST4|TEST5|TEST6|TEST7|TEST8"
>> a = Split(s, "|")
>> WScript.Echo a(Ubound(a))
>>
TEST8
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I cannot use SPLIT as per comment in the question.